# in php, i unset a property of object, but after unserialize , the property is back, why?

Tags: php, serialization

My PHP code is here :

```
class test {
    public $a = 'a';
    public $b = 'b';
    public $c = 'c';
}
$a = new test();
unset($a->a);
$b = serialize($a);
$c = unserialize($b);
var_dump($a, $b, $c);
```

Why does `$c` contain the property `a`?

Comment: `unserialize()` first instantiates a new object. Since your property has a default value, it will get that value, and because you `unset()` it, there's nothing to overwrite it with.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman How is that a duplicate?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Isn't it not?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Is it?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Looks like it to me, but looking at your comment, I feel, it _may not_ be... Should I reopen it?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I'm not a PHP guy, so my comment is just an educated guess, but your duplicate doesn't mention serialization/deserialization anywhere.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I am still not sure, but well, I could see a point with you. Reopened and apologies... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

`unserialize` creates and initialises a new instance of the class (although it doesn't call the constructor), and then maps any property values from the serialized string over the top. Because you're unsetting the property entirely there isn't a value to map back over the default, and so it stays set in your new object.

If you set the property to null rather than unsetting it then it will still be stored in the serialized copy, and the behaviour should end up the same as you intended.

```
$setToNull = new test;
$unset = new test;

$setToNull->a = null;
unset($unset->a);

var_dump(unserialize(serialize($setToNull)), unserialize(serialize($unset)));
```

> object(test)#3 (3) {
>     ["a"]=>
>     NULL
>     ["b"]=>
>     string(1) "b"
>     ["c"]=>
>     string(1) "c"
>   }
>
> object(test)#4 (3) {
>     ["a"]=>
>     string(1) "a"
>     ["b"]=>
>     string(1) "b"
>     ["c"]=>
>     string(1) "c"
>   }

(The difference is that the restored object will still have the `a` property set to null, which isn't *quite* the same as having it unset, but should behave the same in most situations)

As a more complicated solution (or if this doesn't match the behaviour you actually expect) then you might be able to make use of PHP's [`__sleep` and `__wakeup` magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) on your class, which give you finer-grained control of what happens when an object is serialized/unserialized.

Answer (score 0):

When you call unserialize a new object will be created. It's not exactly the same object.

Your class have default values so when you unserialize an object and you don't have $a property being set then a default value will be used.

To see the difference check this code

```
class test {
    public $a = 'a';
    public $b = 'b';
    public $c = 'c';
}

$a = new test();
$a->a= 'property'; // set a to "property"
unset($a->a); // remove a

$b = serialize($a);
$c = unserialize($b); // there is no "a" property set so default value will be used
var_dump($a, $b, $c);
```

If you remove default value from `public $a = 'a';` then it'll be null

```
class test {
    public $a;
    public $b = 'b';
    public $c = 'c';
}



$a = new test();
$a->a= 'property';
unset($a->a);

$b = serialize($a);
$c = unserialize($b);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($a, $b, $c);
```